# Windows 10 desktop-only ux guideline AND show case applications

Tags: gui-design, desktop-application, guidelines, windows-os

I was previously developing Android apps. There we have the very detailed [specification of the Material Design](https://material.google.com/) AND there are apps like Google Mail, Google Drive, Google Docs, Google Calender that strictly follow that specification. I often get my ideas from those apps.

**Now, I'd like to have this same set (specification AND show case apps implementing it) for Windows desktop.** I need it for a powerful desktop-only application to write individual reports in the enterprise sector.

What I found so far:

- Guidelines for Windows desktop that look very much like Windows 7 [(example)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dn742478.aspx). I fear that those guidelines are pretty soon outdated.
- Guidelines for [Universal Windows Platform (UWP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/uwp/layout/design-and-ui-intro) look modern, but did not convince myself yet, that they can get used for powerful thick windows applications. I don't know any show case apps for that.
- Office 2016 seems to use UWP for smartphones and tablets pretty consistent, but I could not find an official guideline they apply to for their desktop (mouse oriented) part.

Comment: This seems to be what you're talking about and *does* fall under the UWP banner: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/design.

However, unlike Material, this seems to be focussed on UX so you're unlikely to find any rules on specifying drop shadows or tile spacing.